# Installing multiple iTunes MSI in Powershell App Deployment Toolkit

Tags: powershell, itunes, powershell-4.0

I have been **told** that I must deploy iTunes across PSADT, to Windows machines. I do not want to run the full .exe and would rather deploy the individual MSI files.

```
$msi = @("$dirFiles\iTunes 64iTunes6464.msi", "$dirFiles\AppleApplicationSupport64.msi", "$dirFiles\Bonjour64.msi")
        foreach($_ in $msi)
        {Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, $_, /passive -Wait}
```

It is picking up the array and is cycling through but I am getting Parameter errors on each file.
New to PS and the various different requirements of each app is completely throwing me.

Is there something stupidly obvious I am missing, or am I barking up the wrong tree with the script construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ArgumentList` takes a string, or string array - so you'll need to use something like the below.

```
$ToInstall = ("iTunes 64iTunes6464.msi", "AppleApplicationSupport64.msi", "Bonjour64.msi")
foreach($Msi in $ToInstall){
    Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec' -ArgumentList "/i ""$($dirFiles + '\' + $Msi)"" /passive" -Wait
}
```

currently it's trying to convert things after the 
`-ArgumentList` into a string, but doesn't know where to stop.

let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That is starting the installer (as previous) but immediately completes. Not looking like it is picking up the MSI files as present

Comment: @user001 apologies that's because I'm an idiot who typo's variable names. try again with the updated version?

Comment: It is and you are not the only one who mistypes. I mistyped the iTunes6464 installer myself!!

Comment: @user001 aha - as long as it ends up working in the end - glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you (especially for actually explaining the -ArgumentList requirement)